# SumatraPDF Bookmarks bar

Tags: texstudio, bookmarks, sumatrapdf

To make my document editing a bit more easier, does anyone know how to get SumatraPDF to display the bookmarks in the bookmarks bar when using it as the PDF viewer?

I am using SumatraPDF + TexStudio. The "Show the bookmarks sidebar when available" radio button is ticked in my SumatraPDF viewer.

When I open the PDF document in, say Phantom PDF, then the bookmarks are shown. I am using the hyperref package if anyone wanted to hint something in that line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DropDown menu at the top left corner->View->Bookmarks` or `F12`.

[image]